# Change values of variables in for loop

Tags: c, loops, decrement

Why is it that the variable 'a' changes along the first declaration of a=x (for x=-6) as the for-loop continues, and why doesn't it change for the decrementation of x?
In short, why is a=-4 at the end of the loop and not a=-8?

```
int main() 
{
   int x,a;
   for (x=-6,a=x;x>-10;--x,a++)
   x--;
   
   printf ("%d %d",x,a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assignment is done first so x=-6, a=-6(deep copy not reference)
Condition check: -6>-10 TRUE 
Loop: x=-7 
Incrementation: x=-8, a=-5

Condition check: -8>-10 TRUE
Loop: x=-9
Incrementation: x=-10, a=-4

Condition check: -10>-10 FALSE; BREAK

Comment: @SupportUkraine: this does not explain the observed behavior.

Comment: It's unclear to me if you think that `a = x` somehow creates a connection between the two variables other than a simple assignment: *"why doesn't it change for the decrementation of x"*. Is that the origin of your doubt?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the *double* decrementation of `x`, the loop runs twice, not four times. Hence `a=-4` is correct. (In any case, `a=-8` would never occur, as `a` is incremented from `-6`.)